# Can I use Lucky Cigarette Case to avoid activating Dark Pact?

Tags: eldritch-horror

Can I use Lucky Cigarette Case to increase a fail roll 1 on 2 and thus avoid activating dark pact condition?

> (2) Lucky Cigarette Case
>
> Trinket
>
> Once per round, you may add 1 to the result of 1 die when resolving a test.

Answer (score 7):

No.

Its effect only applies to *tests* (where you test one of your Investigator's five skills).

It does not apply to checks like the Dark Pact condition has (or any other check where you roll a dice without reference to a specific skill).